# why does my browser does not open the project after npm start

Tags: reactjs

Hello today i want to change something in my project, but when i tried to open the project in browser, it does not open the project and i get message saying "the react app is not responding". Im pretty sure i dont have any error in my code,last time i remmember changing some components but it worked perfectly fine. But now it wont open the project in browser. I dont know how to solve this.

This is the code, i put it in my github : https://github.com/rhmndhika/InstagramAPI

If u can help me pls do, i wanna finish this project. Thank You

P.S Bad english

Comment: Are you running any other project on the same port like 3000? and this one is not started or running on any other port?

Comment: no there are no other project running in the same port. only this project does not open in  the browser. When i tried other project it worked fine. IDK how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your React app has many old deprecated dependency issues that are the reasons it's not working properly. You need to upgrade to latest dependencies or don't use them those are no longer maintained.**

**Take a look inside the terminal**

[image: Take a look inside terminal]